# Remove prerequisites validation from Windows Installer setup project uninstallation

Tags: setup-project, uninstallation, custom-action, prerequisites

We are using Setup Project with windows C# and are using launch conditions to validate some prerequisites while installation. But it occurs in UNINSTALL time also. Can any body suggests, how to **remove the launch condition validation while uninstall** ...

Please let me know any possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REMOVE property is set to "ALL" when you uninstall.

The condition would include '... AND NOT REMOVE = "ALL" '.

Comment: But the property is valid only after InstallValidate standard action.

Comment: Is it? If it is, just move the LaunchConditions action after that!